# Local static variable and multithreading — is it safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, static

If I have

```
pthread_create(newThread, &attr, threadFunc, arg)
```

which is called several times to create  threads that run `threadFunc`, and `threadFunc` is something like:

```
void threadFunc(){      static int x = 0;      }
```

Is this `x` variable shared between all threads? I know it's not in the thread's stack, because it's static, and it sits where global variables are.
If not, and each thread has it's own `x`, there's no need for locks — is that right?

Comment: Alternatively if you want to make it thread safe use thread local storage.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not thread-safe and `x` **is** shared between all the threads. Furthermore, operations on an `int` in C are not guaranteed to be atomic.

Answer (score 2):

That static `x` is shared by all threads that use `threadFunc` as its start routine. If you want each thread has a copy of that `x`, you should use [thread-specific data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#Pthreads_implementation).

Comment: Regular local variables are thread safe, so yes, if you can make it work as a local variable, you should use a local variable.  But then the question becomes — why was it static before?  Always use a regular local variable if you can, rather than a static variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Can we *prove* that local variables are threadsafe? Suppose we have a method that has a local variable and the method never returns and contains an infinite loop which reads and writes that variable. Before doing so, the address of that local variable is stored in a global, and a second thread accesses the local variable via the global alias. Is it threadsafe now?

Comment: The local variable is thread-safe (specific to the thread), but providing the global pointer to the local variable makes it unsafe; it explicitly shares that which was thread-local otherwise, and then requires coordination to access the variable securely.  Read-only access isn't a problem, but any mixing of reading and writing is a potential (if not actual) problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  So what you're saying is that a local is threadsafe if it is used in a threadsafe manner, and not threadsafe if it is not used in a threadsafe manner. Isn't that statement true for *anything*, not just locals?

Comment: @EricLippert: some things are thread-unsafe regardless of how it is used. For example, returning a pointer to static data is not thread-safe. If another thread calls the same function, it is up in the air what your thread gets to see. With automatic local variables, you have to try hard to make them thread unsafe. You have to explicitly ship them to make them accessible to another thread, and you have to worry about when the first thread makes the global pointer to its local variable invalid (by exiting the function).  By default, though, local variables will be thread-safe.

Comment: @EricLippert: with returning a pointer to static data, you can almost make it thread-safe as long as every thread cooperates (by applying an external mutex or something similar).  But that isn't safe if some thread ignores the mutex.  By contrast, a local variable is thread-safe unless you go out of your way to make it unsafe.